# Possible to get custom javascript files to have intellisense in VS 2010?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am writing some scripts that I broke up into separate files. I am wondering is it possible to get intellisense working on my custom scripts.

Say I have Script A with some functions that I need to use in Script B. It would be cool if I could see those functions in Script B while I am typing.

I tried to do the xml reference comment

```
/// <reference path="A.js" />
```

but this does not seem to do anything.

Thanks

**Edit**

// script 1

```
var abc = (function (my, $)
{
    my.events = function ()
   {
        // selectors is from my base file(not shown as I don't think it is needed to be shown)
        // my.selectors.createFrm = '#createFrm'
        var createSubmitFrmHandler = $(my.selectors.createFrm).live('submit', function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

   }

   return my;

} abc || {}, jQuery));

// script 2

var abc = (function (my, $)
{
     my.dialogs = {

        addDialog: function ()
        {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>').dialog(
            {
                width: 580,
                height: 410,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Basic Dialog',
                buttons:
                    {
                        Cancel: function ()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        'Create': function ()
                        {

                            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(my.selectors.createFrm)
                            // this is undefined as page loadup no form was found so live did not kick in
                            my.createSubmitFrmHandler.validate().form();

                        }
                    }
            });

            return $dialog;
        },

    return my;
} abc || {}, jQuery));
```

So I have something like that.

If I am in Script 2 if I go to "my." I see nothing in intellisense.

Comment: You need to give it the full path?

Comment: @ Carnotaurus - They are in the same folder so I would not think I wound not need the full path. I tried the full path just to be sure and nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I declare my function in a file (JScript1.js) and add in the intellisense (the comments)

```
var myFunc = function (myParam) {
    /// <summary>
    /// This is my summary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="myParam" type="String">
    /// This the comment for the parameter
    /// </param>
    /// <returns type="Array" />
}
```

I added `///<reference path="JScript1.js"` to the top of my second script (JScript2.js) and intellisense was available.
I moved the file to a different folder, lost intellisense and then updated the path to be the relative path `///<reference path="../Models/JScript1.js"` and intellisense was available again.

Comment: Hmm this does not seem to work. I am using the Module Pattern. So maybe I don't have scope or something. I will post a little example that I have. Maybe if you could make project that I can download and open up in VS2010 that would be great.

Comment: Did you try it with creating a new file and pasting in the code I put up then creating a second file and attempting to use the function?