# Adding custom JavaScript scripts to intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper plugin and my web application is heavy on JavaScript.

By that I mean there is a lot of libraries (knockout.js, jQuery, jQuery UI - to name a few).

While intellisense works alright in C#, I'm having a hard time to start it working for JavaScript. I've tried googling and going through options, preferences and docs all through out the holidays, but seems that I'm searching for something that just isn't there.

So by example there's a class in knockout.js "ko.utils", which has methods like "ko.utils.arrayMap". My question is, how can I make intellisense (of either R# or VS) index this class and offer me methods when I type "ko.utils.", hence speeding up my development in JavaScript?

Note: [Possible to get custom javascript files to have intellisense in VS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145816/possible-to-get-custom-javascript-files-to-have-intellisense-in-vs-2010) this is not a duplicate I think, because it is seldom for these libraries to have a special VSDoc script here and if they had one, I still couldn't refere it globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [ReSharper plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development) to extend the code completion mechanism to provide the features you need. What you'd have to do is analyze the parsed structures yourself, derive the relevant content to be added to completion lists, and inject it when necessary.

Comment: I guess that could be a good way, yet sounds too hard for such trivial task, or is it?

Comment: What you're asking for is far from trivial.